# Edit a Channel Form with super admin as author

Tags: safecracker, channel-form

After upgrading to EE 2.7.1 ...

I can't edit any channel entries that have the Super Admin as the author, and get this error "The selected author is invalid." (am logged in as a non-super member).

Only happens when using the Channel Form (used to be Safecracker), it's OK in the CP.

All my settings are correct e.g. "Can edit entries authored by others".

Comment: Take a look at the source for the page with the form. Is the author ID correct? It should be included as one of the hidden fields for the form.

Comment: This won't help, members can't edit a Super Admin's entry with a Channel Form. I tried author_id="1" didn't help either.

Comment: did you ever get an answer for this Samsull? I ran into this same problem today.

Comment: I think it was a 2.7.1 bug to do with the default statuses in Channel Form

Answer (score 1):

Pre-2.7, with Safecracker, you were able to go to the Safecracker settings via Add-ons > Modules > Safecracker

[image: SafeCracker Settings]

It doesn't appear you can do this with the new Form element of the Channel module. I'd hit up EE support directly for this.